# How to stop my mobile home's new doors from leaking when it rains?

Tags: doors, leak

We just replaced two exterior doors on our mobile home.  Now both doors leak at the bottom of the door where the door meets the frame. With the doors closed, you can see light at both the corners & we've had one recent storm & all is wet inside. I have tried several different items from hardware stores & nothing fits or works.

What will fix this problem?

Comment: Some pictures would definitely help. Also did you install the doors yourself or did a professional? If a pro, call them back in to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Installing a proper threshold will reduce or eliminate water infiltration under the door.

Notice that water would have to flow uphill in order to pass these adjustable height thresholds:

[image]

The lower one has a sill extension, the upper does not. Products of this type are available for both in-swinging and out-swinging doors.